# How to find obsolete @SuppressWarnings for Sonar Rules?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, suppress-warnings, sonarlint

I'm using

- `SonarQube Community Edition Version 8.4.2 (build 36762)`, and
- `SonarLint for Eclipse 5.5.2.24675`

I suppress certain false positives by using e.g.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("java:S1192") // some comment explaining the suppression
```

However, sometimes, code changes and the suppression does not fit the code anymore. There wouldn't even be a warning anymore, but the suppression might still be in there.

**How can I find obsolete warning suppressions, especially the ones that suppress Sonar warnings?**

I'd guess it must involve SonarQube or SonarLint themselves, since they are the only ones that can actually determine if a warning is obsolete or not.

I couldn't find a Sonar rule for that, which I could activate.
I know there is an eclipse option in *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Annotations -> Unused '@SuppressWarnings' token*, but since eclipse doesn't know about sonar rule identifiers, I have disabled (i.e. set to *Ignore*) the option *Unhandled token in '@SuppressWarnings'*. Therefore, I guess eclipse won't help me here.

My current option would be to grep for `@SuppressWarnings` and review all of them, but that's not a route I'd like to go down. I'd rather like to automatically detect these.

Comment: `Search`>`File...`>enter `@SuppressWarnings("java:S1192")`

Comment: Well, that's the same as grepping. This doesn't evaluate if the suppression is obsolete or not either. I'd still have to review all of the occurrences. Also, `java:S1192` was an example. It's not just about one single rule. It's about all existing suppressions in the code and picking out the ones that suppress a potential warning, which sonar would actually not complain about since the violation isn't even in the code anymore.